# Exclude lib from jar in gradle file

Tags: android, jar, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I try launch android project and get error

```
Error Code:  2
Output: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'    
android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "nit.livetex.livetexsdktestapp"
      minSdkVersion 10
      targetSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
   compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   }   
}    
dependencies {
   compile files("libs/sdk.jar")
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

I think It occurs because of using support-library in sdk.jar.
Where I should add exclude rule?

Comment: it happens when you are using 2 versions of the same dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but can you try that please?

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

or

```
compile files("libs/sdk.jar"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Comment: When I try first case, I get Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'

Comment: If you don't want to fix your gradle to support all exclude operations which is preferable, you can simply open your libs/sdk.jar with an archive manager and delete the bastard (support-v4 folder)